# Zend Server 9: sqlite database locked error while trying to save setup from backend

Tags: sqlite, zend-framework, lighttpd

I try to run Zend Server 9.1 with Developer License on centOS 7.3 (selinux disabled), installed by Zend-Installer bash-script.

However, the admin interface is 
a) very slow
b) gives me "General error 5: database is locked" when trying to save stuff.

I figured out, that lighttpd is locking the DB all the time (usr/local/zend/var/db/zsd.db). Reinitiating the zsd.db file etc. doesnt help.

As soon as I stop the lighttpd process, the database becomes available again.

Any hints, why lighttpd would lock the DB all the time ?

Thx in advance,
Frank

Comment: What version of lighttpd are you running and *what* is locking the database?  A default "lighttpd" server does not lock that dabase.  Something executed by the lighttpd webserver must have been configured to do so.  Maybe look into how you have configured Zend caching.  Maybe provide your lighttpd.conf in your question details if you think that your lighttpd config is causing you problems?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you the reason with out checking the logs file. You can generate Zend Server Support Tool and check the(zend_server_ui.log,zsd.log) logs for the exact reason behind database log.

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/support_tool.htm

However, you can also check the logs from Zend Server UI| Monitoring | Logs.